# Azure notification hubs - how to set multiple apps on the same hub

Tags: ios, azure, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

I have a situation where I need to use the same notification hub for several iOS applications. For a given tag - all the applications should receive this push.

Each iOS app has a different push notification certificate, so only one of the apps actually got the push notification. I don't want to resolve to opening multiple hubs  - because then I need to manage which hub each app could belong to - and this is very awkward.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty certain what you want to do is impossible for several reasons.  iOS push is handled via APNS which is an Apple technology.  Apple dictates that every individual app has to have it's own bundle identifier and therefore it's own specific push certificate.  Notification Hubs doesn't support multiple certificates (or multiple app settings for any of the push providers) so there is no way for an individual hub to push to more than one app.  You're stuck having some sort of management layer built which knows which hub to talk to for which app.  Alternatively, you could just ask all of your hubs to send the same message and use Tags to do the actual filtering (each hub is asked to send a message but only the hub with a device registered with the right tag does).

Comment: I am resorting to the latter - which means I have a ton of redundant calls to irrelevant hubs - but it does seem reasonable that the same hub have several apps - obviously it has one for iOS/Android/Winphone etc. so why not 2 for iOS etc. This use case seems pretty common - I don't want to manage which tag belongs to which hub - Azure should be saving me this headache. Hub is only an abstraction of the various push notification providers and not over the app's certificate.

Comment: I agree and there is an MS Connect request for this functionality somewhere (I don't have the link now). Please vote. Our scenario is that we have an API (as a service provicder) and a generic client app that is re-branded for different customers into the stores. 

There is another possible reason for this limitation: it might be that MS want for various reasons for the developer to separate costs by resource group or by subscription. In some scenarios (eg: as API provider) the ISV or SaaS-provider might be better off having the hub in a subscription billable to a customer.

Comment: This thread is pretty old. I was wondering if there is any update on this.