# Azure notification hub configuration for separate iPad and iPhone apps

Tags: ios, azure, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

I'm trying to configure the Azure Notification Hub for a non-universal iOS app. The Azure management console doesn't allow me to upload two different push notifications certificates, so I'm wondering if there is a way to handle this case. I've tried to export both certificates (iPad and iPhone) in a single p12 file, but the upload of this file on Azure fails with the error:

```
SubCode=40000. Failed to validate credentials with APNS. Error is The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized..TrackingId:527cc6fc-3af6-48a2-a316-ebcb79a6527e_M2_M2_G6,TimeStamp:8/12/2015 8:42:49 AM
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Azure notification hubs - how to set multiple apps on the same hub](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247622/azure-notification-hubs-how-to-set-multiple-apps-on-the-same-hub)

Comment: See basically [the same question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247622/azure-notification-hubs-how-to-set-multiple-apps-on-the-same-hub). You will have to use multiple hubs, one for each certificate, and send the push request to all hubs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NotificationHub setup assumes a single application has multiple platforms, but does not handle the case where the same platform (in your iOS) has multiple implementations.

The solution for this is to create a second notification hub in the same namespace and then register the devices in the proper hub. This would then require logic to send notifications to the right hub (or to always send notifications to both hubs).